# Inserting an entity if it doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-contrib

We've been using `Dapper` and `Dapper.Contrib` for the ease in which we can perform regular database operations, which has been great. However, since introducing `Polly` to add retry policies for some of our operations, I've not been able to find a way to keep the same simplicity because of the necessity to check for a record's existence before executing a retry.

Here's a simplified example of how we're currently performing inserts:

```
public async Task Insert(Payment payment)
{
    var retryPolicy = // Create using Polly.
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var dao = MapToDao(payment);
        await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => connection.InsertAsync(dao));
    }
}

[Table("Payment")]
public class PaymentDao
{
    [ExplicitKey]
    public Guid PaymentId { get; set; }
    // A whole bunch of properties omitted for brevity
}
```

where `Payment` is our domain model, and `PaymentDao` is our data access object.

We do actually have logic in the service that calls `Insert` that explicitly checks for duplicates, but this is negated by the retry policy. This means since the introduction of `Polly`, we are seeing a small number of duplicate payments being inserted.

I can fix this by doing the following:

```
public async Task Insert(Payment payment)
{
    var retryPolicy = // Create using Polly.
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var dao = MapToDao(payment);

        await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => connection.ExecuteAsync(
            @"IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Payment WHERE SubscriptionId = @subscriptionId) = 0)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Payment
                (
                    PaymentId,
                    SubscriptionId,
                    // Lots of columns omitted for brevity.
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    @PaymentId,
                    @SubscriptionId,
                    // Lots of values omitted for brevity.
                )
            END",
            new
            {
                dao.PaymentId,
                dao.SubscriptionId,
                // Lots of properties omitted for brevity.
            }));
    }
}
```

However, as you can see, it becomes pretty long-winded. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: What is wrong with the fix you currently have?

Comment: @Nkosi With some of the legacy objects we have which we've not broken up yet, there are 50+ properties, which leads to a lot of manual mapping of values in the inline SQL. I was just was hoping for something that would allow us to maybe supply a predicate and the dao, and it would take care of the rest. Something like:  `connection.InsertIfNotExistsAsync(dao, predicate)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the alternative of checking first using the model and then performing the insert given that the search uses fewer parameters

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
    var dao = MapToDao(payment);
    var sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.Payment WHERE SubscriptionId = @subscriptionId";
    await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => { 
        var exists = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>(sql, new {dao.SubscriptionId});
        if(!exists) {
            await connection.InsertAsync(dao);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you very much. Have a nice night.